# What happens if the power is removed at the moment the database transaction takes place?

Tags: database, transactions

A transaction is understood as a concept that guarantees that something does not happen or happens. What if the system physically writes to the disk to apply the transaction and a power outage occurs?

Comment: Will leave this as comment but I would imagine amongst other things it depends on if autocommit is enabled.

Comment: As long as the transaction is not committed, it's lost. If the transaction was committed before the power outage, the data will be there once the server restarts and does recovery. The details **highly** depend on the database product being used.

Comment: Wikipedia has a section describing [ACID Implementation strategies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID#Implementation)

Answer (score 0):

As defined by the ACID-Properties of transactions: If the transaction-commit returned successfully before the system is down, then it is guaranteed that the changes have been persisted. If it did not return, but the commit is being processed. The following possibilities exist after the restart of the dbms:

- The database is in the state before the transaction being committed has been started
- The database is in the state, that all changes of the transaction being committed have been persisted and can be found subsequently.